# Why the code of "addOnSuccessListener" is getting skipping during its execution in the following code blocks?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, listener

**1: First code block:** In the following code block, during its execution it is skipping the "addOnSuccessListener", checked many times still not getting any error but the code is not working properly as the part is getting skipped.

```
Hisab.toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()){
    
                        case R.id.today_h:
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "okay hai today", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //                        String todayinmillis;
    //                        long timeinMillies = 0;
    //                        String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    //                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    //                        try {
    //                            Date mDate = sdf.parse(date);
    //                            timeinMillies = mDate.getTime();
    //
    //                        } catch (ParseException e) {
    //                            e.printStackTrace();
    //                        }
    //                        todayinmillis= String.valueOf(timeinMillies);
    //                        Log.d("TAG", "onMenuItemClick: "+todayinmillis);
    //                        sales_items = new ArrayList<>();
    //
    //                        //Showing Bills Data
    //                        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(uUID).document("sales")
    //                                .collection("Bills").whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("date",todayinmillis).orderBy("date", Query.Direction.ASCENDING).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    //                            @Override
    //                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
    //
    //                                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot snapshot : task.getResult()) {
    //                                    String amt = snapshot.getString("amt");
    //                                    String due = snapshot.getString("due");
    //                                    String status_amt =snapshot.getString("status amt");
    //                                    String status = snapshot.getString("status");
    //                                    String date = snapshot.getString("date");
    //                                    String invoice_no = snapshot.getString("invoice no");
    //                                    String name_number = snapshot.getString("name number");
    //                                    String id= snapshot.getString("id");
    //                                    String time=snapshot.getString("time");
    //                                    Sales_Item sales_item = new Sales_Item(amt, date, due, status, status_amt, invoice_no, name_number,id,time);
    //                                    sales_items.add(sales_item);
    //                                }
    //                            }
    //                        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    //                            @Override
    //                            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
    //                                adp_hisab_sales = new Adp_hisab_sales(getActivity(), sales_items);
    //                                recyclerView.setAdapter(adp_hisab_sales);
    //                            }
    //                        });
    //
    //                        //Showing Entry data
    //                        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(uUID).document("sales")
    //                                .collection("Entry").whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("date",todayinmillis).orderBy("date", Query.Direction.ASCENDING).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    //                            @Override
    //                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
    //                                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot snapshot : task.getResult()) {
    //                                    String amt1 = snapshot.getString("amt");
    //                                    String due1 =snapshot.getString("due");
    //                                    String status_amt1 =snapshot.getString("status_amt");
    //                                    String status1 = snapshot.getString("status");
    //                                    String date1 = snapshot.getString("date");
    //                                    String id = snapshot.getString("id");
    //                                    String time=snapshot.getString("time");
    ////                  String invoice_no = snapshot.getString("invoice no");
    ////                  String name_number = snapshot.getString("name number");
    //                                    Sales_Item sales_item1 = new Sales_Item(amt1, date1, due1, status1, status_amt1,id,time);
    //                                    sales_items.add(sales_item1);
    //                                }
    //                            }
    //                        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    //                            @Override
    //                            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
    //                                adp_hisab_sales = new Adp_hisab_sales(getActivity(), sales_items);
    //                                recyclerView.setAdapter(adp_hisab_sales);
    //                            }
    //                        });
                            break;
```

**2: Second code block:** : In the following code block, during its execution it is skipping the "addOnSuccessListener", checked many times still not getting any error but the code is not working properly as the part is getting skipped.

```
toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.fromto:
//                        Calendar calendar;
//                        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
//                        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
//                        int day = calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH;
//                        int month = calendar.MONTH;
//                        int year = calendar.YEAR;
//
//                        datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(BIll.this, R.style.DialogTheme, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
//                            @Override
//                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
//                                //date_of_sale.setText(month + "/" + dayOfMonth + "/" + year);
//                            }
//                        }, day, month, year);
//                        datePickerDialog.show();
                        break;
                    case R.id.paid:
                        list=new ArrayList<>();
                        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(Home.uUid).document("sales")
                                .collection("Bills").whereEqualTo("due","0").orderBy("invoice no", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                                .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                for(QueryDocumentSnapshot snapshot:task.getResult()){
                                    String amt=snapshot.getString("amt");
                                    String due=snapshot.getString("due");
                                    String status_amt= snapshot.getString("status amt");
                                    String status=snapshot.getString("status");
                                    String date=snapshot.getString("date");
                                    String invoice_no=snapshot.getString("invoice no");
                                    String name_number=snapshot.getString("name number");
                                    String id= snapshot.getString("id");
                                    String time=snapshot.getString("time");
                                    Sales_Item sales_item = new Sales_Item(amt,date,due,status,status_amt,invoice_no,name_number,id,time);
                                    list.add(sales_item);
                                }
                            }
                        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                                apd_bills= new Apd_bills(getActivity(),list);
                                recyclerView.setAdapter(apd_bills);
                            }
                        });
                        break;
                    case R.id.unpaid:
                        list=new ArrayList<>();
                        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(Home.uUid).document("sales")
                                .collection("Bills").whereGreaterThan("due","0").orderBy("due", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                                .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                for(QueryDocumentSnapshot snapshot:task.getResult()){
                                    String amt=snapshot.getString("amt");
                                    String due=snapshot.getString("due");
                                    String status_amt= snapshot.getString("status amt");
                                    String status=snapshot.getString("status");
                                    String date=snapshot.getString("date");
                                    String invoice_no=snapshot.getString("invoice no");
                                    String name_number=snapshot.getString("name number");
                                    String id= snapshot.getString("id");
                                    String time=snapshot.getString("time");
                                    Sales_Item sales_item = new Sales_Item(amt,date,due,status,status_amt,invoice_no,name_number,id,time);
                                    list.add(sales_item);
                                }
                            }
                        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                                apd_bills= new Apd_bills(getActivity(),list);
                                recyclerView.setAdapter(apd_bills);
                            }
                        });
                        break;
                    case R.id.today:
                        String todayinmillis;
                        long timeinMillies = 0;
                        String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                        try {
                            Date mDate = sdf.parse(date);
                            timeinMillies= mDate.getTime();
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        todayinmillis= String.valueOf(timeinMillies);
                        //long currentDate=System.currentTimeMillis();
                        Log.d("TAG", "onMenuItemClick: "+timeinMillies);
                        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(Home.uUid).document("sales")
                                .collection("Bills").whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("date",timeinMillies).orderBy("date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                                .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                for(QueryDocumentSnapshot snapshot:task.getResult()){
                                    String amt=snapshot.getString("amt");
                                    String due=snapshot.getString("due");
                                    String status_amt= snapshot.getString("status amt");
                                    String status=snapshot.getString("status");
                                    String date=snapshot.getString("date");
                                    String invoice_no=snapshot.getString("invoice no");
                                    String name_number=snapshot.getString("name number");
                                    String id= snapshot.getString("id");
                                    String time=snapshot.getString("time");
                                    Sales_Item sales_item = new Sales_Item(amt,date,due,status,status_amt,invoice_no,name_number,id,time);
                                    list.add(sales_item);
                                }
                            }
                        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                                apd_bills= new Apd_bills(getActivity(),list);
                                recyclerView.setAdapter(apd_bills);
                            }
                        }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                for(QueryDocumentSnapshot snapshot:task.getResult()) {
                                    String amt = snapshot.getString("amt");
                                    String due = snapshot.getString("due");
                                    String status_amt = snapshot.getString("status amt");
                                    String status = snapshot.getString("status");
                                    String date = snapshot.getString("date");
                                    String invoice_no = snapshot.getString("invoice no");
                                    String name_number = snapshot.getString("name number");
                                    String id = snapshot.getString("id");
                                    String time = snapshot.getString("time");
                                    Sales_Item sales_item = new Sales_Item(amt, date, due, status, status_amt, invoice_no, name_number, id, time);
                                    list.add(sales_item);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        break;
                    case R.id.yesterday:

                        long timeInMilliseconds = 0;
                        Date mydate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                        String yestr = dateFormat.format(mydate);
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                        try {
                            Date mDate = sdf2.parse(yestr);
                            timeInMilliseconds = mDate.getTime();

                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        String todayinmillis2 = String.valueOf(timeInMilliseconds);

                        String todayinmillis1;
                        long timeinMillies1 = 0;
                        String date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                        try {
                            Date mDate = sdf1.parse(date1);
                            timeinMillies1= mDate.getTime();
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        todayinmillis1= String.valueOf(timeinMillies1);
                        Log.d("TAG", "onMenuItemClick: "+todayinmillis2+"  "+todayinmillis1);
//                        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd-MMM-yyyy");
//                        String yestr = dateFormat.format(mydate);
                        list=new ArrayList<>();
                        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(Home.uUid).document("sales")
                                .collection("Bills").whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("date",todayinmillis2)
                                .whereLessThanOrEqualTo("date",todayinmillis1).orderBy("date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                                .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                for(QueryDocumentSnapshot snapshot:task.getResult()){
                                    String amt=snapshot.getString("amt");
                                    String due=snapshot.getString("due");
                                    String status_amt= snapshot.getString("status amt");
                                    String status=snapshot.getString("status");
                                    String date=snapshot.get("date").toString();
                                    String invoice_no=snapshot.getString("invoice no");
                                    String name_number=snapshot.getString("name number");
                                    String id= snapshot.getString("id");
                                    String time=snapshot.getString("time");
                                    Sales_Item sales_item = new Sales_Item(amt,date,due,status,status_amt,invoice_no,name_number,id,time);
                                    list.add(sales_item);
                                }
                            }
                        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                                apd_bills= new Apd_bills(getActivity(),list);
                                recyclerView.setAdapter(apd_bills);
                            }
                        });
                        break;
                    case R.id.week:
                        long week=System.currentTimeMillis() - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                        list=new ArrayList<>();
                        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(Home.uUid).document("sales")
                                .collection("Bills").whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("date",week).orderBy("date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                                .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                for(QueryDocumentSnapshot snapshot:task.getResult()){
                                    String amt=snapshot.getString("amt");
                                    String due=snapshot.getString("due");
                                    String status_amt= snapshot.getString("status amt");
                                    String status=snapshot.getString("status");
                                    String date=snapshot.get("date").toString();
                                    String invoice_no=snapshot.getString("invoice no");
                                    String name_number=snapshot.getString("name number");
                                    String id= snapshot.getString("id");
                                    String time=snapshot.get("time").toString();
                                    Sales_Item sales_item = new Sales_Item(amt,date,due,status,status_amt,invoice_no,name_number,id,time);
                                    list.add(sales_item);
                                }
                            }
                        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                                apd_bills= new Apd_bills(getActivity(),list);
                                recyclerView.setAdapter(apd_bills);
                            }
                        });
                        break;
                    case R.id.month:
                        long month=System.currentTimeMillis() + (24 * 60 * 60*1000*30);
                        //Log.d("TAG", "onMenuItemClick: "+month);
                        list=new ArrayList<>();
                        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(Home.uUid).document("sales")
                                .collection("Bills").whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("date",month).orderBy("date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                                .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                for(QueryDocumentSnapshot snapshot:task.getResult()){
                                    String amt=snapshot.getString("amt");
                                    String due=snapshot.getString("due");
                                    String status_amt= snapshot.getString("status amt");
                                    String status=snapshot.getString("status");
                                    String date=snapshot.get("date").toString();
                                    String invoice_no=snapshot.getString("invoice no");
                                    String name_number=snapshot.getString("name number");
                                    String id= snapshot.getString("id");
                                    String time=snapshot.get("time").toString();
                                    Sales_Item sales_item = new Sales_Item(amt,date,due,status,status_amt,invoice_no,name_number,id,time);
                                    list.add(sales_item);
                                }
                            }
                        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                                apd_bills= new Apd_bills(getActivity(),list);
                                recyclerView.setAdapter(apd_bills);
                            }
                        });
                        break;

                }

                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: #1) The code is all commented, so of course it "gets skipped".

Comment: #2) Which of the 6 `addOnSuccessListener()` calls are you referring to?

Comment: Can you share the toolbar initialization codeblock with the XML file?

Comment: All most all "addOnSuccessListener()" are getting skipped, I know they are commented, but here there is no issues of COMMENTED thing.

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **350** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.